# At what point is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Define $f(x)=\begin{cases}x^2\,\,\,\,\text{if $x\leq 0$}\\ x+1\,\,\,\text{if $x>0$}\end{cases}$At what point is the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous? Justify the answer.

I will separate it into three cases:

Case 1: Let $x_0>0$, then let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to $x_0$. Let $\epsilon=x_0/2$, then there exists an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that all members of $x_n$ is contained in $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ for all $n\leq N$. Then we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x_0+1$

Case 2: let $x_0<0$, apply the similar way as case 1, we can have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x_0^2$

Case 3: let $x_0=0$, and let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{R}$ that converges to $x_0$, but we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0^-} f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x_0^2$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow 0^+} f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x_0+1$, hence $f(x)$ is not continuous.

Can anyone help me to write a better proof by using the definition of sequential continuous? Thanks

Comment: $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Since I need to justify why it is continuous at $x\neq 0$, I need to show why the function is continuous at $x>0,x<0$ and not continuous at $x=0$, right?

Comment: For case 3, you should demonstrate a *specific sequence* for which $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$ does not exist. Such a sequence should have infinitely-many positive terms and infinitely-many negative terms. For the other two cases, you do want to proceed more generally.

Comment: @CameronBuie I could have $x_n=1/n$ which limit is $0$, so $\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(1/n)=1\neq 0$, I confused about to process more generally

Comment: That works just as well (and arguably better)! You've thus shown that $x_n\to0,$ but $f(x_n)$ does not converge to $f(0).$

Comment: @CameronBuie I don't see why $f(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $f(0)$

Comment: Because $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac1n=1\ne0=f(0).$$

Comment: @CameronBuie For case 1 and 2, I don't know how to write more generally. Or do you mean I could just show the limit of $f(x_n)=f(x_0)$?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion! For cases 1 and 2, you must show that if $x_0\ne0$ and $x_n\to x_0,$ then $f(x_n)\to f(x_0).$

Comment: @CameronBuie Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{R}$ and converges to $x_0$. if $x_0>0$, we have $\lim f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x_0+1$; if $x_0<0$, then we have $\lim f(x_n)=f(x_0)=x^2_0$. Do you think these enough to show $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0\neq 0$?

Comment: Every claim you stated in that comment is true. Can you prove each one (using definitions and previously proved results)?

Comment: @CameronBuie $x_0>0$, $\lim f(x_n) = \lim (x_n+1) = x_0+1 = f(x_0)$

Answer (score 1):

The map $f$ is continuous at every $c < 0$; for, let $c < 0$. Then $x < 0$ only if $|f(x) - f(c)| = |x-c||x+c|$; note that $|x-c| < |c|/2$ only if $|x+c| < 5|c|/2$ and only if $|x-c||x+c| < |x-c|5|c|/2$; for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-c| <  2\varepsilon/5|c|$ only if $|x-c|5|c|/2 < \varepsilon$, and hence $|x-c| < \min \{ |c|/2, 2\varepsilon/5|c| \}$ only if $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$.

The map $f$ is continuous at every $c > 0$; for, let $c > 0$. Then $x > 0$ only if $|f(x) - f(c)| = |x-c|$; for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-c| < \varepsilon$ only if $|f(x) - f(c)| < \varepsilon$.

We have proved that $f$ is continuous at every point $\neq 0$; we claim that $f$ is discontinuous at $0$. But $f(x) \to 1$ as $x \to 0+$ and $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0-$ (try to show these); hence $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

Comment: how do you get $|x-c||x+c|<|x-c|5|c|/2$

Comment: By triangle inequality throughout: $|x-c| < |c|/2$ only if $|x| - |c| \leq |x-c| < |c|/2$, only if $|x| < 3|c|/2$, only if $|x|+|c| < 5|c|/2$, and only if $|x+c| \leq |x|+|c| < 5|c|/2$.

Comment: do you get it now? By the way, you have the right here to accept any answer you find which helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well $x^2$ and $x+1$ are continuous on their respective domains, so the only point to check is $x=0$. Obviously, as $x\to0^+$, $f(x)\to 1$ and if $x\to 0^-$, then $f(x)\to 0$. Hence, $f$ isn't continuous at $x=0$

By better do you mean more $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s?

Comment: more $\epsilon$